# Is there a way of storing an object's position in a C# List INSIDE the object?

Tags: c#, list, arraylist, indexing

It should be noted that it's possible for each objects' fields to be indistinguishable from one another within the list and the best way to differentiate them is by ID. It would be extremely helpful if an object's ID could also be its Index in that list.

```
    //...

    receiveData(ClassA obj2Add) {
       maplist.Insert(0, obj2Add);       //Defined as a Maplist, which extends List<ClassA>, assume with no other fields of relevance
       Console.WriteLine(obj2Add.Index); //Should display zero.
    }
    
    class ClassA {
       string mapname {get;set;}
       int Index;               //Would reference this ClassA's position in maplist.
    }
```

Is there anything I can add to ClassA or the Maplist class to fulfill this goal?

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary<int, ClassA>` or a `SortedList<int, ClassA>` where the key would be the index value - or you can write custom logic to your collection and your class to enforce that relationship - however - this would make these two classes tightly coupled and that's usually considerd as a bad thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible **only if your ClassA ID starts from 0** and then you can do something like:

```
 receiveData(ClassA obj2Add) {
       maplist.Insert(0, obj2Add);
       maplist=maplist.OrderBy(o=> o.Index).ToList();
       Console.WriteLine(obj2Add.Index);
    }
```

Why do you need that anyway? I would guess that you want to select the element by `maplist[id]`

If this is the case, then I would suggest using

```
maplis.FirstOrDefault(f=>f.Index==id);
```